# Salesforce record detail page automatically jumping to the middle of the page

Tags: user-interface, detail-page

Was wondering if anyone knows what's behind this issue.

Every time anyone in our org pulls up a record detail page, it will automatically navigate (scrolls down) to the middle of the record detail page. It is quite annoying for our users because then they would usually have to scroll back up to see the detail Account Info or Contact Info. It is doing this on both Chrome and Firefox...

Was wondering if there's anything we can do to stop this from happening for our org?

Also - I have noticed that it only happens on smaller screens (laptop screens), but on my 23' widescreen monitor, it does not jump to the middle as it usually does.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is it a standard page or a VF page? If a VF page it would help if you could share the page. Do you have a date field roughly at the point it "jumps" to? I've seen VF pages focus on date fields like that before.

Comment: It's not a VF page, it's a standard record detail page :(

Comment: Maybe provide some sample URLs? It could be a parameter messing things up.

Comment: Here's a sample link: https://ssl.salesforce.com/00100000006UAje

The jump doesn't happen at home page, or the default landing page when clicked on the standard Accounts or Contacts object. When we drill down into a record, that's when it jumps to the middle...

Comment: @Mark Liu - No one can access that link. Are you sure that the part is is jumping to is not an inline page with an open editable field?

Comment: I know no one can access that link, it's an account in our org. If you could, I would be in trouble haha. Yes, it's jumping and there's not an inline VF page :(

Comment: There must be an inline page. If not, it wouldn't jump.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an embedded Visualforce page on your layout, and that page has at least one field that could be focused, the salesforce library would focus that field. The reason why your larger screens don't jump down is because the field is already visible on the screen, so no scrolling is required.